# how to make node environment code work on websites online?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am pretty new to vanilla js (coming from node.js) I want to clear how do i display this on my website which is hosted online

Is there any tool i can use to make it work in webpage.

this is simple puppeteer demo code (from docs) and i need to run it in my webpage

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap150102.html', {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
  });
  await page.waitForTimeout(2000)
  await page.waitForSelector('img');  
  // await page.waitForInterval(2000)

  await page.pdf({ path: 'filez.pdf', format: 'a3', fullPage: true });


  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: No. Puppeteer is a Node library.

Comment: @Andy so is there no way i can make it work in webs.

Comment: Why would you want to? You've explained you're from a Node background - why not put the experience to good use and build a little server that serves up the information you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) is a headless Chrome (Chromium) browser wrapper that opens a Chrome instance and works with its APIs to automate things like UI testing, etc.
it's not possible to use it on the client side.

as they mentioned in their [docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer#api--faq--contributing--troubleshooting):

> Puppeteer is a **Node library** which provides a high-level API to control Chrome or Chromium over the DevTools Protocol. Puppeteer runs headless by default, but can be configured to run full (non-headless) Chrome or Chromium.